# Access same value with one of multiple keys in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector, key

I need a way to access a value by passing in any key that the value could have.
For example, a player object that can be accessed by either their ip address or name?

To illustrate.

`Player1 has ["a", "1.2.3.4"]`

`Player2 has ["b", "3.4.5.6"]`

`Player3 has ["c", "2.2.9.3"]`

So, to access Player2 I could use `players["b"]`, or `players["3.4.5.6"]`

Should I just iterate over a vector for that? But I plan to have anywhere around 100 elements, so would a tree-like container be better than an array list?

Could you use `std::multimap` for that?
Or even in `std::map`?

Comment: What you probably need is [`boost.bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: You can use two `std::map`s having same references for objects by corresponding keys. Each time you add/remove an object just update both maps.

Comment: How would you remove the reference from both maps by dealing with one of the maps?

Comment: Can *name* be a valid *ip address* ?

Comment: The _name_ will be an in-game nickname.

Comment: Why not just dump the player into the map twice, under both string keys "a" and "1.2.3.4"?

Comment: Because removing both elements at once would be quite tricky when I need to remove a player.

Comment: *I was going to do that, but how would removing the reference from both maps work through just one of them?* - you can receive an object by `name` then you can find what `ip` this object has, use both keys to remove items from both maps.

Comment: I see now. So keep a copy of _name_ and _ip_ in the _player object_, then depending on whether I access the name/ip map, erase at the alternate from the other map. Thank you.

Comment: there's a problem in this design. what happens if 2 players behind the same NAT router choose the name nickname? That would be a duplicate key.

Comment: Duplicate nicknames are forbidden. And I'm still _very_ new to networking but, put the _port_ in the _ip_ key as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure `ip` and `name` are unique.

```
map<string, Player> byNameMap;
map<string, Player> byIpMap;

void add(Player p) {
    byNameMap[p.name] = p;
    byIpMap[p.ip] = p;
}

void remove(Player p) {
    byNameMap.erase(byNameMap.find(p.name));
    byIpMap.erase(byIpMap.find(p.ip));
}

// assuming you are sure player with such name exists
void removeByName(string name) {
    remove(byNameMap[name]);
}

// assuming you are sure player with such ip exists
void removeByIp(string ip) {
    remove(byIpMap[ip]);
}
```

Comment: Note that your map content are unrelated, I mean that `byNameMap.at(name).score++;` won't change the one from `byIpMap`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`boost.bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) as in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

int main() {
  typedef boost::bimap<std::string, std::string> Ipmap;
  typedef Ipmap::value_type NameIpPair;

  Ipmap players;
  players.insert(NameIpPair("a", "1.2.3.4"));
  players.insert(NameIpPair("b", "5.6.7.8"));
  players.insert(NameIpPair("c", "9.10.11.12"));

  std::cout << players.left.at("b") << std::endl;
  std::cout << players.right.at("5.6.7.8") << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fce9f6aa0e3355c)

Comment: I would need a _key-key-value_ since value will be a _PlayerObject_ and not a hashed string.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that u have a player array and 2 pointer arrays pointing the start point which are char value and ip adress.
Doesnt matter what searching algorithm u use bjt include both searchin with and little if statement. For example:
If(incoming_value_size ==1)//which is a char val
Then
Search through set in set1array
Otherwise 
Set2array

//if your players sorted, you can find one with their neighbour values whicj you represent by 2 pointers. Get the index and you ll be ok

Comment: I do this a lot, but this time, when players are being added and removed at  unknowable points in time, there's an enormous chance things can get jumbled up between arrays, plus searching by key would be faster for a map in my case since I'm gonna have anywhere from say 5 to 500 players at a time. Too slow to search through a vector or plain array.